# Producing valid sum from answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple numeracy game. Basically where I am at, at the moment is I have a grid that is populated with numbers. On the side of the grid are the numbers 0-9. When a hidden number in the grid is highlighted the user should click the correct one on the side. If it is right it should take on the "wordglow3" class and if it is wrong it should take on the "wordglow4" class. When a whole number is completed (if it is more than one number long). Some additional classes should take over to determine whether the whole number is right or wrong. Right would be "wordglow2" and wrong would be "wordglow".

Basically the aim is to produce a sum at random which makes the number in the grid the answer of the sum. I was going to do this by manually by listing a number of sums attached to each number, but I think it would be better if the script produced a sum depending on the answer highlighted in the grid. This way there wouldn't be as much back end editing and there would be more randomization.

I have looked for examples of this online but havn't had any luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the list at the moment..

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="answerlist">

    <li data-answer="1" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="2" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="3" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="4" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="5" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="6" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="7" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="8" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="9" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="10" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="11" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="12" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="13" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="14" data-add=""></li>

    <li data-answer="15" data-add=""></li>

  </ul>
```

As you can see I want to start off with addition and then progress to the harder operators once I know how to do it.

Here is the script that accepts the users choice..

```
if ($('.drop-box.spellanswer').length == answerIsCorrect) {

                $('.drop-box.spellanswer').addClass('answerglow2');
                $(right).val('Right!');
                $(right).show();
                success.play();
                $(wrong).hide();
                score.right++;
                score.attempts++;

                if (score.right == 3) {

                    $('.answers').css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $('.answers').html("Well done! </br> You correctly spelt " + score.right + ". </br> Keep it up.").show();
                    $('table').fadeOut(3000);
                    $('.right').hide();
                    $('.box-style2').hide();
                    $('.box-style').hide();
                    $('.picstyle').hide();
                    $('.play').hide();
                    $('.minibutton2').hide();
                    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
                    audio.stop();
                    $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
                    pic.hide();

                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('.minibutton').trigger('click');
                }, 1500);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery(right).hide();
                }, 1500);

            } else {

                $('.drop-box.spellanswer').addClass("answerglow4").css('color', 'transparent');
                $(wrong).val('Wrong');
                $(wrong).show();
                failure.play();
                $(right).hide();
                score.wrong++;
                score.attempts++;

                if (score.wrong == 3) {

                    $(".minibutton").css('visibility', 'visible').prop('disabled', false);

                }

                $('.drop-box.spellanswer').animate({
                    'opacity': 1
                }, 2000, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('answerglow4').removeClass('occupied').html('')

                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery(wrong).hide();
                }, 1500);
            }


        }
    });

}

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood well what you ask, but you might want to have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkEnT/50/). If it's a good base for what you need I'll post it as an answer.